# Extra tag that would be great if were included

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have recently posted about using a 2-Wire speaker with Arduino Esplora, however I couldn't tag it correctly because there was no `arduino-esplora` tag. The Esplora tag would be very useful in case anyone posts about an Arduino Esplora, and anyone looking to answer questions about the Arduino Esplora. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: It seems that an "Arduino-esplora" and "Esplora" tag have been made today. I believe that completes your question. You should accept @NickGammon's answer since it's also right (and the question is resolved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tag should be created (from scratch) if you use it. It doesn't have to exist in advance.

Comment: `It doesn't have to exist in advance.` You need 150 rep for that, though. The OP only has 28.